# Ruby on rails: passenger showing error on going to the apps domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I have installed Ruby on Rails, Apache and Passenger. When I try to run the application its showing the following error:

```
An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read this article for more information about this problem.
Raw process output:

/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

I'm using:

```
 Ruby 2.1.5p273
 Rails 4.2.0
 Phusion Passenger version 4.0.58
 Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

I'm running Ruby on my server for the first time with Passenger.